# Spotify - How to pause track and resuming track

Tags: ios, swift, audio, spotify

So I make an application that allows user to stream song from spotify, I have no problem in playing and stop using spotify player. But however I'm having problem to pause and resume the song.

Here's the logic that I have:

1. Stop current playing track
2. get current playback position when i stop the spotify player
3. play and seek to the time that i got

and here's my code:

```
var currentOffset = User.spotifyPlayer!.currentPlaybackPosition
            println(currentOffset)

            var spotifyTrackUrl : NSURL = NSURL(string: self.spotifyTrackUri!)!
            User.spotifyPlayer!.playURIs([spotifyTrackUrl], fromIndex: 0, callback: { (error : NSError!) -> Void in
                if error != nil {

                    println(error)

                }else{

                    if User.spotifyPlayer!.isPlaying == true {

                        User.spotifyPlayer!.seekToOffset(currentOffset, callback: { (error : NSError!) -> Void in

                            if error != nil {

                                println("rene 3")

                                println("spotify seek error : \(error)")

                            }

                            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "playicon.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

                            println("rene 4")
                        })

                    }

                }
            })
```

I always got below error:

> spotify seek error : The operation failed due to an unspecified issue.

I'm using swift, but give me any suggestion doesn't matter if you use obj-c

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to use `seekToOffset` to pause and to resume a song you only need the method below:

```
if self.player?.isPlaying == true {

               self.player?.setIsPlaying(false, callback: nil)
    }else{


    self.player?.setIsPlaying(true, callback: nil)


    }
```

Comment: your suggestion is for stop the player and play again from the start, what i need is pause and then resume playing from current position when I pause the player. Thanks btw

Comment: Actually it's not for play again from the start, its function is to pause the player, it is mentioned at its documentation just try it.  here is the link of its documentation https://developer.spotify.com/ios-sdk-docs/Documents/Classes/SPTAudioStreamingController.html#//api/name/setIsPlaying:callback:

Comment: have you tried that? I've tried your solution and it's not pause and resume

Comment: Yes, it's working for me, the code I've posted before is under a Play/Pause Button, it's strange that it is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only trying to pause and resume the player, you should use built-in methods for **SPTAudioStreamingController**, like:

```
[self.player setIsPlaying:!self.player.isPlaying callback:nil];
```

If you are trying to show visual part of the track progress, I would suggest to use something like NSTimer and update the view, like:

```
 -(void)updateTimerTickTock:(NSTimer*)sender
{
NSUInteger currentTime = self.spotify.playbackManager.player.currentPlaybackPosition;
NSUInteger totalDuration = self.spotify.playbackManager.player.currentTrackDuration;

if (totalDuration > 0)
{
    float prg = (float)currentTime/totalDuration;
    [self.prgView setProgress:prg animated:YES];

    if ((totalDuration - currentTime) < 20 && !hasRequestedNextTrack)
    {
        [self.delegate playComponentRequestsPreloadOfNextTrack:self];
        hasRequestedNextTrack = YES;
        self.readyToPostPlayedSong = YES;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: your suggestion, is stop and play from the start. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Actually it does pause and resume for me. It soes not start again from 0.

Answer (score 0):

For resuming you should use the method:

playURIs:withOptions:callback:

Here's a quick example:

```
NSURL *trackURI = [NSURL URLWithString:uriString];
    float startTime = 34.3;
    SPTPlayOptions *options = [[SPTPlayOptions alloc] init];
    [options setStartTime:startTime];
    [self.spotifyPlayer playURIs:[NSArray arrayWithObject:trackURI] withOptions:options callback:^(NSError *error) {

        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"*** Starting playback got error: %@", error);

            return;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Playing");
        }

    }];
```